# Analytical evaluation of the integral

Tags: integration

Is there any analytical way to prove that the integral $\int_{2.04}^\infty \frac{\sin x}{x^2}dx$ is nonegative?

I tryed to use geometrical approach, i.e. the graph of the integrand look like:
[image]

The magnitude became smaller and smaller, since $\sin x$ is multiplied by the decreasing function $1/x^2$, so the third area, which is positive, is bigger then the forth one, which is negative, and so on. BUT I dont know what to do with the first two areas(

OR integration by parts gave me 
$\int_{2.04}^\infty \frac{\sin x}{x^2}dx=\frac{\sin(2.04)}{2.04}-Ci(2.04)$, where $Ci(x)$ is the cosine integral function.

Comment: any try????????

Comment: It's a little tricky, since the integral changes sign and becomes negative if the lower bound is increased just past $2.156$.

Comment: Substituting $u=\frac{1}{x}$, the integral becomes: $\int_{\frac{51}{25}}^{\infty}\frac{\sin{x}}{x^2}\mathrm{d}x=\int_{0}^{\frac{25}{51}}\sin{\left(\frac{1}{u}\right)}\,\mathrm{d}u$. Not sure if that'll be helpful though.

Answer (score 1):

The integral from $a$ to $\infty$ is $-Ci(a) + \dfrac{\sin(a)}{a}$, where $Ci$ is the "[cosine integral](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/CosineIntegral.html)" function.  So you want fairly accurate approximations for $\sin$ and $Ci$ at $2.04$.  Numerical methods...

Comment: I suspect it's possible to find an analytical argument; but, given how close $a=2.04$ is to the integral swapping sign, one would have to do a _very_ careful inequality argument.

Comment: Yes, because if $a=2.05$ then the integral is negative.

Comment: @Rtep: I get that it's still positive until $a\approx 2.16$. [WolframAlpha](http://bit.ly/UFHEph)

Comment: Sorry, my fault, I were calculating different integral